# MySQL Request with IN clause, with array of couple identifier

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a user table with a couple as identifier : `id` and `type`, like this :

```
id | type | name
----------------
15 | 1    | AAA
16 | 1    | BBB
15 | 2    | CCC
```

I would like to get a list, matching both id and type.

I currently use a concat system, which works :

```
SELECT u.id,
    u.type,
    u.name
FROM user u
WHERE CONCAT(u.id, '-', u.type) IN ('15-1', '16-1', '17-1', '10-2', '15-2')
```

But, I have the feeling it could be better, what would be the proper way to do it ?

Thank you !

Comment: Your way honestly doesn't seem that bad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use the following approach in mysql

```
with dat as 
(
 select 17 id, 1 type, 'AAA' t
 union all
 select 16 id, 1 type, 'BBB' t
 union all
 select 17 id, 2 type, 'CCC' t
)
-- end of testing data 
select *
from dat
where (id, type) in (
 -- query data
  (17, 1), (16, 1)
)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was seeking ! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can separate them out. Not sure if it's more efficient but at least you would save the concat part :

```
SELECT u.id,
    u.type,
    u.name
FROM user u
WHERE (u.id = 15 AND u.type = 1) 
OR (u.id = 16 AND u.type = 1) 
OR (u.id = 17 AND u.type = 1) 
OR (u.id = 10 AND u.type = 2) 
OR (u.id = 15 AND u.type = 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

`IN` can operate on "tuples" of values, like this `(a, b) IN ((c,d), (e,f), ....)`. Using this method is (should be) faster as you are not doing a concat operation on "a" and "b" and then comparing strings; instead you are comparing pairs of values, unprocessed and with an appropriate comparison operation (i.e. not always string compares).

Additionally, if "a" and/or "b" are string values themselves using the concat technique risks ambiguous results. *("1-2","3") and ("1","2-3") pairs concat to the same result "1-2-3"*

Comment: This is exactly what I was seeking ! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends a lot on how you obtain the values for id and type that you use for filtering

If they are results of another computation they can be saved in a temporary table and used in a join

```
create TEMPORARY TABLE criteria as 

select 15 as id, 1 as type
UNION
select 16 as id, 1 as type
UNION
select 17 as id, 1 as type
UNION
select 10 as id, 2 as type
UNION
select 15 as id, 2 as type

  SELECT u.id,
    u.type,
    u.name
FROM user u
  inner join criteria c on u.type = c.type and u.id = c.id
```

The other option is an inner query and then a join or a WITH clause (which is rather late addition to Mysql arsenal of tricks)

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know about temp tables, thank you